# How can I send data to other apps with Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to share an image with other apps, but I couldn't do it with Ionic.
How can I use intents with Ionic (to do something like this http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I created a sample project and uploaded in  [git hub](https://github.com/anilkumar007/social-share) for your social sharing requirement via popup in Ionic framework and the reference for the link is social sharing , Please have a look at README.md file for step by step procedure
Having any queries reply

Comment: Hi, Anil, thanks for helping me. This instructions might be useful in my projecto. But I'd like to use Android's intents because my APP should be able to send images to other APP just like when you havê to choose a picture from the gallery.

Comment: hi..how to receive data from other apps?can you help me in this??

Comment: Means .. How do you want the user data login via google/facebook @varunaaruru